# How do i open text editor using a command line on Cloud9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9-ide

I am new at RoR .. i am using Cloud9 IDE for building my application, i would like to know the command line to open the text editor.

I have tried Gedit but it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to change what your editor is pointing to. Then you can just type the shortcut to open the editor. For instance since you are using RoR I am going to assume you are on a Mac. If you wanted to change it to say VIM. Now I obviously don't know where you have cloud9 installed since you left that out. You would need to change the portion of the syntax below after "EDITOR" and point to Cloud9 instead of VIM. I hope this helps, if you have any questions or would like to give more details I could help you further.

```
echo "export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the hosted cloud9 than it's not possible right now to open a file in cloud9. We have a prototype of this feature and are planning to release this asap.